# How to convert sparse matrix to dense matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I think this is a basic question about R. 
I have a data frame of 3 columns, of which the first two columns represent the row and colunm index respectively and the last column is the value. Simplely, the data is in the sparse matrix format. I want to convert it to the standard matrix format. What should I do? The code 
`mat[data[,1],data[,2]]=data[,3]`is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear about the `class` of 'mat' and `class` of columns in `data'.   Assuming that 'data' is`data.frame`and 'mat' is a`matrix`

```
mat[as.matrix(data[1:2]) <- data[,3]
```

Or

```
mat[cbind(data[,1], data[,2])] <- data[,3]
```

---

The approach in the OP's post result in the LHS of the asssignment being

```
mat[data[,1], data[,2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
```

where as the indexing by converting to a `matrix` with `as.matrix` or `cbind` gives equal number of elements on both LHS and RHS of `<-`

```
mat[as.matrix(data[1:2])]
#[1] 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
mat <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
data <- data.frame(row = c(1, 1, 3), col = c(2, 5, 1), 
     value = c(20, 15, 12))
```

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks a lot. And would you mind explaining the principle of this problem?

Comment: @XiaoWen  indexing to get specific elements works as a matrix where as your method is subsetting the columns and rows that.  It could include those elements but it also  have the whole column or row